# Two Separate .xaml files into one window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml, kinect

I have ColorStream.xaml and SkeletonStream.xaml files, and I would like to put the SkeletonStream view in the bottom-right corner of the ColorStream window. Is that possible?

And if so, how would I connect the two, especially with the xaml file? Sorry, I'm pretty new with C#. I feel like it should just be an extra line, and I tried looking at the KinectExplorer example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but is there a reason for having two xaml files? I would think you could just combine the xaml code into a single xaml file and use something like a grid to separate the sections. Like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>

// Bottom Right
<Stackpanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
```